# foursquare api test push works with venue id but not the actual checkin

Tags: push-notification, real-time, foursquare

The test push works, also test push with the venue id.
I'm put as manager for that venue and I have the application that does the push
as an authorized service on my account.

Should this do the trick ?
Actual checkins don't result in any push.
I see there's also connected apps which state you haven't connected any apps yet but I can't seem to connect to my app in any way

Although when going to foursquare.com/app/*clientID* I see it's connected since the button shows disconnect possibility.

Anyone has a clue on what needs to be changed ? Is it the fact that it's in developer mode ? Cause I'd like to keep it that way...

Cheers,

Jonas

Comment: Developer mode shouldn't matter. What push API are you subscribed to? If this is user push, you can only see pushes for users that have [authenticated](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) your app. If this is venue push, a manager of the venue you're trying to receive pushes from must have authenticated your app. After proper authentication, you should be starting to see actual check-ins.

Comment: It's the venue push. I am manager of the venue and the application shows up as an authorized service of my account. Although it doesn't show up under connected apps, it is connected though when going straight to foursquare.com/app/ClientID.

Something probably went wrong but I can't seem to find out what.
Maybe I didn't get the whole OAuth thing.

For the realtime Venue api does it needs to do any OAuth for every push or just once to link the app to my account ?

Comment: As soon as you (the venue manager of venue XYZ) authorizes your app that subscribes to venue push, your app should start seeing check-ins to venue XYZ. Just as a sanity check, perhaps 1) try disconnecting and authorizing again, and 2) make sure you opted for venue push in your app settings, not user push http://cl.ly/image/1B250W3e1R0P

Comment: Hmm, stil not working with an actual checkin. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps, but i figured, that if you already checked-in recently (sorry, I cannot provide you with more information about what recently means for foursquare) in the same venue, the push will not get triggered.

Another reason may be the privacy-settings of the user checking-in. I have no proof for that, yet, but not having activated "Include me in the public list of people who are currently checked in at a venue" or "Let venue managers see when I check in to their business, or when I am one of their best customers" might suppress the push as well.

Kind regards, Thomas